# Unable to get value for an object from Hashmap, even though it returns the same hashcode

Tags: java, oop, java-8, hashmap, equals

[image]//Unable to get the value of an object in hashmap after overriding its hashcode 
//This is the item class where i generate hascode based on the item name

```
 public class Item {
                    private String name;
                    private Long id;
                    private double price;
                //Constructor
                    public Item(String name, Long id, double price) {
                        this.name = name;
                        this.id = id;
                        this.price = price;
                    }

                    public String getName() {
                        return name;
                    }

                    public void setName(String name) {
                        this.name = name;
                    }

                    public Long getId() {
                        return id;
                    }

                    public void setId(Long id) {
                        this.id = id;
                    }

                    public double getPrice() {
                        return price;
                    }

                    public void setPrice(double price) {
                        this.price = price;
                    }
                //Generating hashcode based on name comparing if item id are //same        
                    @Override
                    public int hashCode() {
                        return name.hashCode();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                        return ((Item) obj).id ==(id);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        return "Item {" +
                                " name='" + name + '\'' +
                                ", id=" + id +
                                ", price=" + price +
                                '}';
                    }
        //Here there are items but when i pass the exact same item with exact //credentials i get null while checking how many items are there using Hashmap.
                public class Warehouse {
                    Map<Item, Integer> itemList = new HashMap<>();
                    List<Drone> drones = new ArrayList<>();
                    private Drone drone;
                    private String sourceAddress;
                    private Address address;

                    public Warehouse(Address address) {
                        this.address = address;
                        Item item = new Item("PlayStation 4 pro", (long) 100, 42000);
                        Item item1 = new Item("X box one S", (long) 200, 40000);
                        Item item2 = new Item("Apple Macbook Pro", (long) 500, 82000);
                        Item item3 = new Item("Dell Xps Laptop", (long) 1000, 92000);
                        Item item4 = new Item("iPhone 7 plus", (long) 2000, 72000);

                        itemList.put(item, 10);
                        itemList.put(item1, 20);
                        itemList.put(item2, 40);
                        itemList.put(item3, 50);
                        itemList.put(item4, 20);

                    }

                    public Drone getDrone() {
                        return new Drone();
                    }

                    public void setDrone(Drone drone) {
                        this.drone = drone;
                        System.out.println("Drone # " + drone.getDroneID() + " has arrived at the warehouse " + address);
                    }

                    public Address getAddress() {
                        return address;
                    }


                    public ArrayList<Item> getItemList() {
                        return (ArrayList<Item>) itemList;
                    }
                //Setting the item
                    public void setItem(Item item) {
                        Integer num = itemList.get(item);
                        if (num == null) {
                            num = 0;
                        }
                        this.itemList.put(item, ++num);

                    }
```

//This is where i'm facing the issue, if i query the hashmap for the same item it returns me null, Item even returns the same hashcode

```
                    public Item removeItem(Item item) {
                        Integer num = itemList.get(item);
                        //## Issue is i get null in num 
                        if(null!= num||num!=0  ){
                            itemList.put(item,num-1);
                        }
                        System.out.println(item);
                        return item;
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] - there's a *lot* of irrelevant code there. (Then format it more readably.) Ultimately the problem is the inconsistency between `equals` and `hashCode` though...

Comment: I am not sure if a mcve is actually needed here. The only thing missing is somebody willing to lookup the appropriate duplicated question.

Comment: @Eugene But i'm still not convinced, as the per the explanation. If i have two items . One in the Warehouse hashmap and I;m getting item2 in removeItem- method. Item item1 = new Item("X box one S", (long) 200, 40000); Item item2 = new Item("X box one S", (long) 200, 40000); , Then if i generate the hashcode for the name, Hashmap will check if the hashcode of both the item names are same right? So for item1 and item2 as long as the name is same we get the same hashcode. if we compare id in equals that shouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: @Federico: it's at least *a* bug. Now that we have a complete example, it's easier to find more problems... It would be better if it were minimal, of course.

Comment: @Federico: No, it&#39;s a bug. It is trivial to construct two objects which compare as equal but have different hash codes, with no other changes to the object. That's a bug, plain and simple. It's not what's breaking this particular example, but that doesn't stop it from being a bug.

Comment: @Federico: Exactly. The presence of a bug isn't determined by whether this particular example happens to demonstrate it.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: Let's put it another way - suppose all the `id` values were small, such that boxing them ended up with the same reference. Would that have caused you to say that the reference comparison wasn't a bug? I would hope not. There are two bugs here, both important - I don't see what's so controversial about that, or why there's any need for sarcasm.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: Excellent, glad we're on the same page.

Comment: @JonSkeet Will you please let me know what the issue is? I'm feeling a bit lost.

Comment: Both have been explained at length. 1) You're comparing Long references, rather than the underlying long values. 2) Your hashCode method is inconsistent with equals, as you're using different fields.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot! yeah actually I can still keep the name.hashcode and if i make my id long instead of Long it works even with "==". So "==" returns false for object comparison because it checks the memory reference right?

Comment: Yes, so if you compare distinct but equal Long objects, == will return false. But no, you shouldn't keep using name.hashCode if you're using the id in equals. *Why* are you insisting on keeping this inconsistency? Either use the name, or use the id, but use the same thing in both methods.

Comment: @RaghavendraSS No, you shouldn't use name in `hashCode`, but `id` instead, as you are using `id` in `equals`. That was the whole point of the discussion (exchange?) between Jon and me.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yes I do agree with you and Jon, but i felt like as long as the names of the objects return the same hashcode, why can't i compare the two ids in equals method. I feel like constrained. But name.hashcode works, all i had to do was making the Long id to long id. Also is it the right way to think that Long id == id didn't work because they had different memory location? because two objects can't be in the same memory location?

Comment: @RaghavendraSS you are correct regarding the comparison of Long objects. But keeping name on hashCode is a bug, Even though it works with your dataset, because you can construct two items with the same ID that return different hash code. Granted that you are not doing this, so you are not *seeing* the bug, but your solution would be much more robust if you used the same set of attributes in both methods.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yeah a great lesson learnt from this mistake, Thanks to you guys for making me realise the importance of hash and equals, also how it works in Hashmap! One last doubt so when we compare primitive data types like int with "==" does it check what's the memory address of the primitive data type? like int a =2; and if we do  if( a == 2) will return true because 2 is from same memory address?

Comment: @RaghavendraSS Glad we could help you. Regarding primitive types comparison, you can safely use `==`, because primitive types aren't references to objects, but just values. If you have `long n = 2` and `long m = 2` and then you compare if `n == m`, the result will be `true`, since `n` and `m` are just values. But if you declare `Long p = 2` and `Long q = 2` and then you compare if `p == q`, the result will be `false`, because `p` and `q` are references to different objects in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object's `hashCode` used the `name` property, but your `equals` uses the `id` property. This violates the contract. Objects for which `equals` returns true must have the same `hashCode`.

`HashMap` uses both `hashCode` and `equals` to locate a key. First it locates a bin within the `HashMap` based on the `hashCode`. Then it goes over all the entries in the bin using `equals` to find the key you are looking for. When `hashCode` doesn't match `equals`, two objects which you consider to be equal may be mapped to different bins, so using `map.contains(key)` to find the key stored in the `Map` will fail.

I think it would make more sense to use `id` as the criteria for equality, so I'd write:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof Item))
        return false;
    return ((Item) obj).id.equals(id);
}
```

Note that I used `equals` for comparing the `id`s. Comparing objects with `==` (`Long`s in your case) is usually wrong.

Also, you might want to make your `equals` method more safe by checking the type of `obj` before casting it to `Item`, and returning false if the type doesn't match.

P.S. based on your new code, you have another problem :

This condition :

```
if(null!= num||num!=0  )
```

will either be true (if `num != null`) or throw a `NullPointerException` (if `num` is `null`).

Therefore it will only put `item` in the `Map` if it's already in the `Map`. It's not clear what the desired logic is, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: Thanks Eran, will you please give a lucid explanation of what's going on !

Comment: Basically right, buth both askers and yours `equals()` method make an unchecked cast to `Item` - wouldn't pass any code review!

Comment: Actually your approach works, but i'm still not able to understand what i missed! why can't we generate hashcode based on one field and check equals on other?

Comment: @GyroGearless true, I just fixed that.

Comment: @RaghavendraSS Did you modify `hashCode`?

Comment: yeah it works if the same field id.hashcode and in equals also if i use id! but what if i have a situation where i want hashcode on a name and equals on some other parameter?

Comment: I feel I'm missing something :( Will you please help me understand. Because both the objects returned the same hashcode when I printed.

Comment: @RaghavendraSS The `equals` method and the `hashCode` method have a contract described in the Javadoc of the `Object` class. If you violate the contract, you can't expect JDK classes such as `HashMap` and `HashSet` to function properly.

Comment: So in future, if I use 2 or more fields to generate the hash code for example : if i use name and id to generate hash code, I need to use the same fields in equals method too?

Comment: @RaghavendraSS yes.

Comment: About the if(null!= num||num!=0  )
actually, the Warehouse has the items so I'm trying to retrieve the items from the warehouse, if the key matches then I will decrement the value by 1. Suppose there are 20 pieces of Xbox if I take 1 Xbox the warehouse Xbox number should reduce to 19.

Comment: @RaghavendraSS In that case you need `if(num != null && num != 0 )`

Comment: So as per your explanation, In my previous implementation, it will look inside hashmap for the hash code of the Item name right? as long as the item that i'm getting inside removeItem method has the same name then it should generate the same hashcode right?  public Item removeItem(Item item) -- in this if i pass the same item as already in the hashmap if name has the same hashcode then equal should work fine right?

Comment: @Eran I have attached the screenshot of the hashcode of both, using name as the parameter for generating the hashcode. In both the cases i get the same value but still why when i iterate for the key it return null i'm not able to understand.

Comment: @Eran Actually the real issue is in equals method using "==" which returns false. If i use .equals() it returns true.

Answer (score 3):

The decision of *where/which* bucket some Entry goes is taken based on your `hashcode`. But there could be *many* entries in that bucket.

So `equals` is called to identify the Entry you are interested in. Since `hashcode` and `equals` are un-related (different properties) that introduces inconsistency.

So suppose you have this:

```
  EntryA (hashCode = 42, id = 2)
  EntryB (hashCode = 44, id = 2)
```

These entries are `equal` based on `id`; but since they have different `hashcodes` they will go to *different buckets* in the HashMap, in different parts.

So now you will have two same entries (according to equals) in the Map - that is why hashcode and equals must be *consistent with each other*.

Comment: But i'm still not convinced, as the per the explanation. If i have two items . One in the Warehouse hashmap and I;m getting item2 in removeItem- method. Item item1 = new Item("X box one S", (long) 200, 40000); Item item2 = new Item("X box one S", (long) 200, 40000); , Then if i generate the hashcode for the name, Hashmap will check if the hashcode of both the item names are same right? So for item1 and item2 as long as the name is same we get the same hashcode. if we compare id in equals that shouldn't be an issue right? –

Comment: ` EntryA (hashCode = name.hashcode, id = 2)
  EntryB (hashCode = name.hashcode, id = 2)`  as long as they are same then why it fails? I'm passing the same name in the objects